# UITextView not picking up text input iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, uitextview, uialertview

i have UITextView and i want to show a alert if empty

```
.h
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITextView *textField;

.m
- (IBAction)next:(id)sender {
if ([self.textField.text length] == 0) {
            UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error!"
                                                                message:@"text empty"
                                                               delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alertView show];
}
}
```

alert is not showing and i can move on without any text being inputted. can anyone help me figure out why?

thanks

Comment: ***first*** don't use `textField` as variable name. ***second*** are you sure, it is properly connected in IB?

Comment: im calling on textField, i have also tried `NSString *message = self.textField.text;` and put the message variable in the if statement but also does not work

Comment: print `NSLog(@"message===%@--", message);` and let me know what you see...

Comment: @FahimParkar yes its connected.

Comment: use NSLog or breakpoint to find what exact is problem. Did you get any value when you enter in text field

Comment: just say `textField.text` instead of `self.textField.text` and let me know what NSLog gives you...

Comment: @FahimParkar lol, nothing prints in nslog and i can not put textfield.text and error comes up and i have to put _ or self

Comment: make sample project and upload on dropbox or somewhere... also try to give myTV as variable name and retry...

Comment: you get NSLog or NSLog itself don't get printed?

Comment: ***Its working perfectly with me***. **I am sure, something is not connect. Please upload your project**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked this from my end and its working perfectly.

[Here is download link for testing the project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/refruz04pqhvc60/AnyVideoPlay.zip?dl=0)

[image]

I am sure, textview is not connected to IB.

If its is connected to IB, then I would say to upload sample project on dropbox to check from our end.

Comment: thanks for showing me that i am doing the exact same thing but its not working for me im not sure why. i have connected everything in the outlets

Comment: @smithyy : I will again say, upload your sample project and let me see what is going wrong....

Comment: thanks i have solved it my next button was linked to next view controller as push segue i removed it and manually created segue so it now works.

Comment: @smithyy : post answer as self answer and mark it as answered... so that others will know what was the problem...

Answer (score 1):

There is a possibility of the `textField` having whitespace characters. Try trimming out any possible whitespace using the following:

```
NSString *text = [self.textField.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet];
if ([text length] == 0) {
    ....
}
```

Comment: Can you do an NSLog for `[self.textField.text length]` and tell me what it shows?

Comment: @smithyy : can I have project link?

Comment: What do you mean by does not show anything? It doesn't give any value in the nslog or the nslog doesn't happen at all?

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
- (IBAction)next:(id)sender {

    NSCharacterSet *whitespace = [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet];
    NSString *trimmed = [self.textField.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:whitespace];
    if ([trimmed length] == 0) {
         // Text was empty or only whitespace.
         UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error!"
                                                            message:@"text empty"
                                                           delegate:nil 
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
   }
}
```

Comment: have you set delegate for TextView?

Comment: yes in header file but when i right click on textview in storyboard delegate is not connected?

Comment: @smithyy : its working with me... I tried locally and it works